# VB script logic error

Tags: vbscript

I have the following snippet of code from a vbscript:

```
            For Each Modified in Files
                If IsEmpty(file1) or IsNull(file1) Then
                    file1 = Modified
                Else
                    file2 = Modified
                    If hDisk.FreeSpace > 900000000000 Then Exit For
       ERROR HERE-->ElseIf file2.DateLastModified < file1.DateLastModified And DateDiff("D", file2.DateLastModified, Now) > 7 Then file2.Delete
                    ElseIf file1.DateLastModified < file2.DateLastModified And DateDiff("D", file1.DateLastModified, Now) > 7 Then 
                        file1.Delete
                        file1 = Modified
                    End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
```

When I try to compile the script, I get an error that I'm missing an 'End', more specifically **Expected 'End' Code 800A03F6**.

I've combed over the code several times and can't seem to figure out why it's giving my this error.  And yes, I also tried the using 'End' as opposed to 'End If'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure for ElseIf is:

```
If c1 Then
   ..
ElseIf c2 Then <-- Not Else
   ..
ElseIf c3 Then
   ..
Else <-- last to catch all else
   --
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got 3 `End If`'s, but you're only starting 2 `If`'s. If I'm reading this right, you could do the following:

```
            For Each Modified in Files
                If IsEmpty(file1) or IsNull(file1) Then
                    file1 = Modified
                Else
                    file2 = Modified
                    If hDisk.FreeSpace > 900000000000 Then
                        Exit For
                    ElseIf file2.DateLastModified < file1.DateLastModified And DateDiff("D", file2.DateLastModified, Now) > 7 Then
                        file2.Delete
                    ElseIf file1.DateLastModified < file2.DateLastModified And DateDiff("D", file1.DateLastModified, Now) > 7 Then 
                        file1.Delete
                        file1 = Modified
                    End If
                End If
            Next
```

The main thing being that if you are going to use the `ElseIf`'s, you can't add the stuff after `Then` on the same line as the `Then` - you can only do that if your `If` statement is all contained on the same line.